# Encapsulating a reference to a native object in a .Net delegate in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, wrapper

Let's assume there is a static .Net method

```
static void RegisterDelegate(Action<array<Object^>^>^ handler);
```

defined in some assembly we can't modify.

I do have the following code:

```
static void HandleCallback(Action<array<Object^>^>^ handler, NATIVE_CPP_TYPE *nativeObject){
    //some code here
}

static void TestCall(NATIVE_CPP_TYPE *nativeObject){
    //RegisterDelegate(??);
}
```

where `NATIVE_CPP_TYPE` is some non-serializable and native-only type which can't be modified either.

A call to `TestCall(ptrToObj)` should now create a delegate of type `Action<array<Object^>^>`. This delegate should call `HandleCallback` when invoked and pass both, its own argument (the Object array) and the pointer to the native Object which was originally passed the the `TestCall` function. Therefore the pointer needs to be stored in some kind of closure.

Do you have any idea how this can be done? I thought about the `System::Linq::Expressions` namespace, but afaik I can't encapsulate native objects in that kind of expression.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in C++/CLI you can't do managed lambdas.  Of course, you can just create your own class that stores the native type and then exposes a method to be used as the delegate:

```
public ref class ManagedClass
{
    static void RegisterDelegate(Action<array<Object^>^>^ handler)
    {

    }
};

class NATIVE_CPP_TYPE
{

};

static void HandleCallback(array<Object^>^ handler, NATIVE_CPP_TYPE *nativeObject)
{     
    //some code here 
}  

public ref class HandleCallbackWithNativeType
{
    NATIVE_CPP_TYPE * m_pNativeObject;

public:
    HandleCallbackWithNativeType(NATIVE_CPP_TYPE *nativeObject)
    {
        m_pNativeObject = nativeObject;
    }

    void Execute(array<Object^>^ array)
    {
        HandleCallback(array, m_pNativeObject);
    }
};


static void TestCall(NATIVE_CPP_TYPE *nativeObject)
{
    // This type will act as your closure "capturing" nativeObject.
    HandleCallbackWithNativeType ^ pHandler = gcnew HandleCallbackWithNativeType(nativeObject);
    Action<array<Object^>^>^ handler = gcnew Action<array<Object^>^>(pHandler, &HandleCallbackWithNativeType::Execute);
}
```

It's not as convienent as the lambda syntax, but it does the job.